# Is pdflscape compatible with pdfx?

Tags: pdflscape, pdfx

The following code triggers an error when using pdflscape.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
%\usepackage{pdflscape} % breaks things
\begin{document}
Hello World
\begin{landscape}Hello from down under\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

The error is:

```
150: Package pdflscape Error: Neither pdfTeX, PostScript, nor dvipdfm driver found.

See the pdflscape package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.150   }\@ehc

 319 words of node memory still in use:
```

This holds with lualatex/texlive 2017.

EDIT

The followig test shows exactly the same problem, but the proposed solution is not applicable.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

In this case, pdfpages triggers the pdflscape error. The problem sits in the pdfpages source code, where pdflscape.sty is loaded. It is a bug.

Comment: Not an expert with `pdfx`. Try with `\usepackage[luatex]{pdflscape}` and see whether all works.

Comment: while the bug is in pdfx package as I show in my answer, @egreg's workaround is equally applicable to your second example, just add the line that he shows before you load `pdfx`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in `pdfx.sty` the code

```
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\ifxetex
 % override the \ifpdf check
 \pdftrue
\else\ifluatex
 \pdftrue
\fi\fi
\RequirePackage{xmpincl}
\ifxetex
 % revert \ifpdf
 \pdffalse
\else\ifluatex
\pdffalse
\fi\fi
```

sets `\ifpdf` to false for luatex which is wrong and breaks any later packages that are testing for pdf output.

```
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\ifxetex
 % override the \ifpdf check
 \pdftrue
\else\ifluatex
 \pdftrue
\fi\fi
\RequirePackage{xmpincl}
\ifxetex
 % revert \ifpdf
 \pdffalse
\else\ifluatex
%\pdffalse
 \pdftrue
\fi\fi
```

is a simple fix although forcing it to use `\pdftrue` isn't correct either if you want to support `dvilualatex` the correct value is set by the `ifpdf` package, but it isn't clear what is the intention of this code section so here I just suggest the simple fix of setting the value to true for luatex.

Comment: Thank you. The authors of the package should look into it. Hopefully a patch will be distributed soon.

Comment: @Rupert you could report it to them....

Comment: Done. They may join us in this thread.

Comment: A better fix is: 
`\newif\ifpdfx@pdfcheck
\ifpdf \pdfx@pdfchecktrue \else \pdfx@pdfchecktrue \fi
\pdftrue
\RequirePackage{xmpincl}
\ifpdfx@pdfcheck \pdftrue\else\pdffalse\fi `
which reverts to the value of `\ifpdf` after temporarily changing it to load the `xmpincl` package.

Comment: Interesting, I used some of the `pdfx` code for my own rendition in `novel` class, but since only LuaLaTeX is permitted, driver-specific problems don't show. Neither do PDF/A problems, since only PDF/X is supported. I did notice some oddities in the `pdfx` package (not duplicated in my own code), but they are unrelated to the issue here.

Comment: @ozross-RRM presumably even better would be to get xmpincl updated so it didn't use `ifpdf` incorrectly (which is I assume the problem here)

Comment: if you want to save/restore, no need for a \newif just \let\savedifpdf\ifpdf \RequirePackage{xmpincl}\let\ifpdf\savedifpdf` should be all that's needed

Answer (score 5):

If you load `pdflscape` before `pdfx` there is no error.

On the other hand, the documentation of `pdfx` recommends to load it first; in this case do

```
\usepackage[luatex]{pdflscape}
```

Apparently `pdfx` sets something that make it impossible to `pdflscape` to correctly guess the used engine, when it is LuaLaTeX.

Comment: `pdfx` uses `\immediate\write` to place information in the PDF, then later writes PDFInfo, which must agree. If the necessary information (which includes layout, title) is not available at the time `pdfx` is loaded, there will be an error, although the message may be obscure. If any of the necessary information is changed after `pdfx` is loaded (such as by `\newgeometry`) then `pdfx` might not notice the problem, but the PDF will definitely be non-compliant, even if compile succeeds. My own modification of `pdfx`, part of `novel` class, auto-loads when changes can no longer be made.

Comment: see my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

There may still be problems with LuaLaTeX and `pdfx.sty`, since primitives were changed. For example, the XMP Metadata may not be uncompressed.
There's an easy fix for this too.

Within  `pdfx.sty` use the following code quite early:

`\let\real@lua@pdfobj\pdfobj
  \def\pdfobj{\immediate\real@lua@pdfobj uncompressed }%`

then  `\let\pdfobj\real@lua@pdfobj`  after the XMP packet has been written.
You could use these lines (surrounded by `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` within the preamble, surrounding `\usepackage{pdfx}`.